# How to include a class in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

This is a very basic question but I can't figure it out.

I have a class that could be named myClass.php, this is a standalone PHP script that contains a standard object definition like this:

```
<?php

class myClass
{
  public function myFunction($param1, $param2){
    return $param1*$param2;
  }
}
```

All I want to do is to be able to call to this class from a model, this is from App/Models/MyModel.php be able to simply do $myClass = new MyClass();

Where should I store myClass.php in the file structure and how can I make it visible for MyModel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll note that you have a 'vendors' directory inside the root (ie, on the same level as the 'app' folder). This is for placing non-CakePHP related files that are shared across applications. You also have an 'app/Vendor' directory, which is for storing non-CakePHP files that are specific to that one app.

So, it should go in one of these two directories - most likely, in app/Vendor.

There's a little bit to know about loading vendor files - you can read the details [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files).

In your case, you probably just need:

```
App::uses('myClass', 'Vendor');
```